# How to ignore these path patterns with hg ignore of mercurial

Tags: mercurial, hgignore

I am quiet novice to Mercurial and I would like to ignore all files included in the followinf patterns:

folder1/folder2/folder3/Res1
folder1/folder2/folder3/Res2
folder1/folder2/folder3/Res3

I have used regex function as follow bu this did not work, any helo please :

```
syntax: regexp
folder1/folder2/folder3/Res*
```

Thanks
Zied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sort of mixing glob and regexp style here. The following should work:

```
syntax: regexp
folder1/folder2/folder3/Res.+
```

Comment: Thanks! for your answer it worked however what if I would like to consider any subfolder : folder1/anyfolder/folder3/Res.+

Comment: @Ziwdigforbugs this should work: `folder1/[^/]*/folder3/Res.+`